# Postgres JDBC in scala unable to run two queries without restarting sbt

Tags: postgresql, scala, jdbc, sbt

I am connecting to a postgres database with scala (2.9.2).

First time I make a SELECT (by running the code with 'run' in the sbt terminal in IntelliJ) it works well, but if I do 'run' again in the sbt shell I get an error that claims:

```
[error] (run-main) java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://localhost/db
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://localhost/db
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:602)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
    at SequenceGenerator$.connect(Validator.scala:50)
    at SequenceGenerator$.generate(Validator.scala:54)
    at Main$.main(Validator.scala:32)
    at Main.main(Validator.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
```

I have installed the postgres connector through sbt, this row in my build.sbt file.

```
libraryDependencies += "postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.1-901.jdbc4"
```

This is my code for making a SELECT:

```
object SequenceGenerator{
  def connect() = {
    DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost/db","user", "pass")

  }
  def generate() = {
    val db = connect()
    val st = db.createStatement
    val res = st.executeQuery("SELECT value from table LIMIT 2")
    while( res.next) {
      println(res.getString("value"))
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We had to add this to our integration tests startup to get around the same issue with the mysql jdbc driver:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance
```

I'm not sure why SBT unloads the driver, but something like this would probably work for you:

```
object SequenceGenerator{
  //Use whatever your jdbc driver class should be here, I'm just guessing
  Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver").newInstance

  def connect() = {
    DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost/db","user", "pass")
  }
  def generate() = {
    val db = connect()
    val st = db.createStatement
    val res = st.executeQuery("SELECT value from table LIMIT 2")
    while( res.next) {
      println(res.getString("value"))
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you are trying to load the driver using the old DriverManager approach. You have to use Database.forDataSource approach in slick and use a proper Database Pool like C3P0.

I think this is a classloading issue between Slick, SBT and the Driver.

Obviously make sure that the driver is in the classpath.